# Enforcing strict policies on S3 file content

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My company has built an awful lot of tools, which all use S3 as a backing store, and read and write CSV files.

We have run into issues around the tools using various encodings, CSV separators, etc. I would like to enforce some strict policies on S3. For example, "all files in bucket X must be valid CSV files in a UTF-8 encoding".

I can see that you can set some basic S3 policies on the file name (like only accept *.CSV), but nothing like what I want.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? My ideas so far are:

- Run a lambda trigger that will notify me if an invalid file was uploaded, so I at least know this happened
- Write a service that wraps the S3 API and does this strict checking, and only grant our tools access to this service

Comment: Your two ideas are basically your only options. Either create a service which does the checking and will only write files if they pass your validation, and then use that service for all s3 access, or a lambda which gets triggered and checks whether the written file is valid. It would make more sense to create a service and prevent bucket access to anything other than that service, to enforce its use.

Comment: I have found a third possibility... You can set a bucket policy to reject files under the condition `"Condition": {"StringNotEquals": {"s3:RequestObjectTag/foo": "bar"}}`. Then, you have to specify a tag `foo=bar` on upload. I can write a layer that checks files before uploading with this tag. That will then encourage (if not force) tools to use this checking layer before uploading files.